# Hibernate query with ResultTransformer crash

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an HQL query and it works fine. Though when I add result transformer to get a result as Map, I got and Exception. I tried to debug inside of Hibernate classes, and find that at

```
  org.hibernate.transform.AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.transformTuple(AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.java:55)
```

**String[] aliases** - array variable is null. I tried further debug hibernate classes one by one, and find that this variable is the member of QueryLoader class, called previously on call stack, but I cannot get when **aliases** array initialized. Please help to understand why it crashes, and is it possible to solve this?

Here the code, I get problem with

```
        Query query = session.createQuery(
                "From User u WHERE u.fleetID =:fleetID");
        query.setParameter("fleetID", fleetID);
        //if I add this code string - request crashes
        query.setResultTransformer(AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE); 
        //crash becomes here
        query.list();
```

Here stack trace:

```
Severe:   java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.transform.AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.transformTuple(AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.HolderInstantiator.instantiate(HolderInstantiator.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.getResultList(QueryLoader.java:438)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2227)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2222)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:470)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:355)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1247)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
    at ca.gfisystems.jag.admin.Controller.buildUserTable(Controller.java:9534)
    at ca.gfisystems.jag.admin.Controller.processRequest(Controller.java:1811)
    at ca.gfisystems.jag.admin.Controller.doPost(Controller.java:2035)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletFilter.doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Whats in `AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE`?

Comment: Not sure understand your question. What you mean? Should I check something?

Comment: I mean that problem may be in transformer. For example it can set null somewhere.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't notice that transformer is standard hibernate class.

Comment: Yes right. It is a hibernate class